# Separating local variables in a Terraform Script to multiple folders

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, rules, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to refactor my code of provisioning an `azure_sentinel_solution` with `sentinel_alert_rules` through Terraform.

Since there are huge queries for each alert rule, I want to know whether there is a way to split them to separate folders. I'm looking for a structure like below.

```
|-- queries
     |
     |-- rule_1_query.tf
     |-- rule_2_query.tf
     |-- rule_3_query.tf
     |-- ...

|-- main.tf
|-- variables.tf
|-- outputs.tf
```

and to use the rule_1_query in my main.tf file.

I tried putting the query in the way of above directory structure. But it won't let me access the queries in my main.tf file.

```
resource resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "rule_1" {
  query = local.rule_1_query
}
```

above code doesnt work.

If you know how can I get this done, a help is much appreciated.

Comment: "above code doesnt work." - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors? What is `local.rule_1_query`?

Comment: Terraform extension does not identify rule_1_query as a local variable. @Marcin

Comment: Why would it? This is not how TF works. Not sure what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use local values for non-local data, and so indeed that doesn't work because this is not an appropriate language feature to use to solve this problem.

If you need to share some data between multiple Terraform modules then one way to do that would be to write a [data-only module](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/composition#data-only-modules).

The documentation I linked to talks about a module that contains only `data` blocks but you can also, if you wish, write a module that has no resources in it at all and consists entirely of hard-coded output values:

```
output "rule_1_query" {
  value = "whatever value"
}
```

Then you can call this module from your root module and access its output values [in the usual way](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs#accessing-child-module-outputs).

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I'll have a look on these :)